# stop tab key event propagation in chrome after an action

Tags: javascript, tabs, textarea, keycode

In Chrome, Im trying to intercept a tab key press stopping ALL normal tab key behavior and perform my own action.

I can stop the default behavior if thats all I do. But if perform an action then try to stop the default behavior it prevents the focus shifting to the next input but it puts a tabspace in the current input.

If the problem is still unclear, please see [this jsFiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/qD2rk/7/)

Here's what I've tried, (note that all of the below work to do what I need in firefox, just not in chrome)

```
<input type="text" class="next-tab"/>
<input type="text" class="next-tab2"/>
<input type="text" class="next-tab3"/>

$('.next-tab').keydown(function(e){
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        console.log(code);
        if (code == 0 || code == 9){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    // this only blocks the propagation of the tab keypress event, and works as expected:
    });

$('.next-tab2').keydown(function(e){
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        console.log(code);
        if (code == 0 || code == 9){
            alert("test");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

        }
});
$('.next-tab3').keydown(function(e){
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        console.log(code);
        if (code == 0 || code == 9){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("test");
            //putting the alert after doesnt help

        }
});
```

**How can I stop the tabspace from being added to the input?**

Comment: The problem seems to be specific to `alert()`. I changed it to `console.log()` and the problem went away.

Comment: `prompt()` and `confirm()` also have the same symptom. I think it's because these display a dialog and that steals the focus away from the element.

Comment: ah, you are completely right, I didnt catch that. Throw up an answer and ill accept it, thank you!

Comment: It's not an answer, it's just a clarification of the problem. I still don't know how to prevent it from happening, other than not calling these functions.

Comment: For me it was the solution, I was just alerting an array while debugging my real code for easy referencing. Since I dont really need to show an alert removing it fixed my problem. If someone comes out with a solution later that allows the alert ill change it to their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only occurs when the action includes `alert()`, `confirm()`, or `prompt()`. It probably has something to do with the way they re-enter the event loop. So remove these debugging statements from the code and it should work.